# How to use polymorphic type constructors in dhall

Tags: haskell, dhall

I am trying to define a polymorphic type in Dhall. In Haskell it would look like:

```
data MyType a = Some a | SomethingElse
```

To do so I have defined this function in Dhall (mkMyType.dhall):

```
let SomethingElse = ./SomethingElse.dhall  in λ(a : Type) → < some : a | somethingElse : SomethingElse >
```

I have also defined a function that returns the constructors for that type, given a (./mkMyTypeConstructor.dhall):

```
λ(a : Type) → constructors (./mkMyType.dhall a)
```

Now, in order to use it I need to do something like:

```
(./mkMyTypeConstructor.dhall Text).some "foo"
```

Is this the right way to do this?

Finally, what would be ideal to have in my use case would be a type that would type check both against for instance a Text such as "foo" and a custom type, for instance { somethingElse: {} }. Is this possible?

Comment: At least for this case, your type reimplements `Optional a`; the union isn't necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll use a union type analogous to Haskell's `Either` to keep the following examples self-contained.

Suppose we save the following `Either.dhall` file:

```
-- Either.dhall
λ(a : Type) → λ(b : Type) → < Left : a | Right : b >
```

We *could provide a `makeEither.dhall` file like this:

```
-- makeEither.dhall
λ(a : Type) → λ(b : Type) → constructors (./Either.dhall a b)
```

... and then we *could* use that file like this:

```
[ (./makeEither.dhall Text Natural).Left "Foo"
, (./makeEither.dhall Text Natural).Right 1
]
```

... but that that would not be ergonomic.

For example, writing `./makeEither.dhall Text Natural` repeatedly is not necessary since we can reduce the repetition using a `let` expression, like this:

```
    let either = ./makeEither.dhall Text Natural

in  [ either.Left "Foo", either.Right 1 ]
```

Also, note that we could have used `constructors` and `Either.dhall` directly in about the same amount of space:

```
    let either = constructors (./Either.dhall Text Natural)

in  [ either.Left "Foo", either.Right 1 ]
```

... which means that we no longer need the intermediate `makeEither.dhall` file any longer.

The final example is the approach I would recommend.  Specifically:

- Use a `let` expression to avoid repeated use of the `constructors` keyword
- Have the end user call `constructors` themselves instead of doing so for them

For your latter question, I think that should go in a separate StackOverflow question.

**Edit:** Note that the `constructors` keyword is now obsolete and you can now just write:

```
let either = ./Either.dhall Text Natural

in  [ either.Left "Foo", either.Right 1 ]
```

For more details, see:

- [Migration: Deprecation of `constructors` keyword](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/wiki/Migration%3A-Deprecation-of-constructors-keyword)